# How do I prove that this is a Homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have a question about the following problem:

> Endow $\mathbb{RP}^n$ with the structure of topological manifolds with $U_k=\{[x]\in \mathbb{RP}^n : x^k\neq 0\}$ with $x=(x^0,...,x^n)$ the canonical linear coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. Then define $$y_k:U_k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n; \,\, [x]\mapsto \frac{1}{x^k}(x^0,...,x^{k-1},x^{k+1},...,x_n)$$Show that this is a homeomorphism.(we have just shown that $\mathbb{RP}^n$ can be interpreted as a quotient space)

I know that I need to show that $y_k,y_k^{-1}$ are continuous ($y_k$ is bijective). But I don't see where we use the structure of topological manifolds. Because I would have proven continuity by saying that $\frac{1}{x^k}(x^0,...,x^{k-1},x^{k+1},...,n^n)$ is clearly polynomial in each component and since $x^k\neq 0$ it is continuous in each component. But this is equivalent to say that $y_k$ is continuous.
I'm not sure if this works because I have never used the structure of topological manifolds.

Could someone explain me if this still works?

Since @Paul Frost told me that my proof isn't complete yet I want to add the rest so that other readers can look at it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see any problem with your approach and its properties as a manifold do not seem relevant to the argument. You are tacitly using topological arguments when you claim polynomials are continuous functions though which is fine. You may want to explicitly make mention that non-zero reciprocation, scalar multiplication, and the constant map are continuous as well. From what I can see the inverse function will not require the manifold structure either.

Comment: ah perfect thanks so then for the inverse function I could also take the same approach. I claimed that the inverse is given by $$y_k^{-1} (x^0,...x^n)=[(x^0,...x^{k-1},1,x^{k+1},...nx^n)]$$

Comment: You're using the manifold structure when you assert (correctly) that each $n$-tuple from $(x^0, \dots, x^n)$ is a set of local coordinates for projective space.

Comment: ah okei so but I didn't do this intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the statement in your question is *to prove* that $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is a topological manifold. To do so, it does not make sense "to use the structure of topological manifolds". You cannot use something what you have to show.

It is clear that the $U_k$ form an open cover of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. You know that $y_k$ is bijective, thus in fact you need to show that $y_k,y_k^{-1}$ are continuous.

Let $p : \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ denote the quotient map. Then $V_k = p^{-1}(U_k) = \{ (x_0,\ldots,x_n) \mid x_k \ne 0 \}$ which is open in $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. The restriction $p_k : V_k \to U_k$ of $p$ is a quotient map: Let $W \subset U_k$ be a set such that $p_k^{-1}(W)$ is open in $V_k$. We have $p_k^{-1}(W) = p^{-1}(W)$, thus this set is open in $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. Hence $W$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and therefore open in $U_k$.

1. $y_k$ is continuous.
   The function $z_k : V_k \to \mathbb R^n, z_k(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \dfrac{1}{x^k}(x^0,...,x^{k-1},x^{k+1},...,x_n)$, is continuous. Since $z_k = y_kp_k$, we conclude that $y_k$ is continuous.
2. $y_k^{-1}$ is continuous.
   The map $j_k : \mathbb R^n \to V_k, j_k(u_0,\ldots,u_{n-1}) = (u_0,\ldots,u_{k-1},1,u_k,\ldots,u_{n-1})$, is continuous. Thus $j'_k = p_kj_k : \mathbb R^n \to U_k$ is continuous. We have $y_k j'_k = id$, hence $j'_k = y_k^{-1}$.

Comment: sorry but is my approach from above wrong?

Comment: @Wave You proved correctly that the function which I called $z_k$ is continuous. This is an essential part of the proof, but it does not give a complete argument.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood the problem. I thought that since you wrote that we should endow $\mathbb{RP}^n$ with the property of topological manifolds, we should assume that. But does the task want me to first show that $y_k$ is a homeomorphism and then show that the set is second countable, hausdorff and locally euclidean with the charts $(U_k,y_k)$?

Comment: I just reread your proof. Did I understand it correctly? You showed in your proof that your $z_k$ (i.e. my $y_k$) is continuous and also its inverse - you just did this in a different way. But now we have to show that the topology is second countable and Hausdorff. (We have already shown Hausdorff in a previous sub-task).

Comment: @Wave Yes. The fact that the $y_k$ are homeomorphisms proves that the space is locally Euclidean. If you know that it is Hausdorff, then it remains to show that it is second countable. The map $z_k$ is not the the same as $y_k$, it is related to $y_k$ by $z_k = y_kp_k$. If you know that $p_k$ is a quotient map (which I have shown), then you can conclude that $y_k$ is continuous.

Comment: Okey perfect I added a complete solution, does this work like this now?

Comment: @Wave It works except one gap: The continuity of the map $y_k$. Your argument shows that the map $z_k$ (see my answer) is continuous. But you need an additonal argument to show that this implies the continuity of $y_k$. See again my answer and my above comments.

Comment: sorry I don't get it, your $y_k$ is the one given in the exercise right? but mine is also the one given in the exercise, what is the difference. could you explain it maybe again. So I don't see why your argument is needed.

Comment: @Wave The function $y_k$ is defined on a subset of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. To prove ist continuity, you need to refer to the **topology of $\mathbb{RP}^n$**. When you say it is continuous in each component $x_i/x_k$ you consider it is as a **function on a subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$** (for this function which is I called $z_k$ this is obvious). That is the gap in your approach.

Comment: ah perfect thanks. But could we immediately say that with the quotient topology the quotient map is always continuous so also the composition with $z_k$ is and thus $y_k$ is continuous?

Comment: @Wave You need to invoke the following (fairly obvious) fact: If $p : X \to Y$ is a quotient map, then for each open $U \subset Y$ the restriction $p : p^{-1}(U) \to U$ is also a quotient map. This allows to conclude that the continuity of $y_kp_k$ implies the continuity of $y_k$. For $y^{-1}_k$ you only need to know that $p_k$ is continuous. Read again my answer.

Comment: perfect thanks.